# Magento 1 Capture Successful Checkout Steps

Tags: magento, google-tag-manager

am working on a little project which is to integrate google tag manager. The client wants to capture all successful checkout steps as follows:

1. Login
2. Billing
3. Shipping
4. Shipping Method
5. Payement
6. Review

Right now the solution I have is to hook into the function gotoSection in the opcheckout.js.

Is there another neat way of doing this?

Comment: Which Magento version are you working with? For Magento 1.x there is already a couple of paid and free extension on Magento Connect - see: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=google+tag+manager&pl=0

Comment: Its magento Enterprise 1.14.2 .. and yes there is but those extension don't cover the requirements.

Comment: What is the requirement that is not fulfilled? I am using one of the free ones and it's working perfectly. If we know the exact requirements we can maybe help you better. All the steps you wrote above are covered with the extensions on Magento Connect.

Comment: Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly Magento has an ajax checkout - you could use  [global ajax event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) (or [Ajax responders](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Responders/) respectively, I think the last time I did something like this Magento used Prototype for ajax call) and check the response url. Prototype example would look something like this:

```
if(Ajax.Responders){
    Ajax.Responders.register({
      onComplete: function(response){
        // last segment if response.url should hold the step name
        // then push it to the datalayer
      }
    });
}
```

Jquery would probably look somewhat like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings ) {
   // check xhr.responseText for step name
   // then push it to the datalayer
});
```

It's been a while and I'm not sure if the Magento checkout still works that way, but you should give it a try - I used to do that so I would not have to modify Magento files (global ajax handlers hook into the ajax event from "the outside"). I used to insert ga calls into the success events, but you can just as easily push the step name and a custom event to the datalayer and use this from inside GTM.

Comment: Hi Eike, yes your correct it uses ajax calls for some steps but not for all steps e.g login step,  shipping and billing steps, but thank you for your answer it helped. I hooked into the gotoSection function which is only called when the previous checkout steps was successful.